# flutter instance of 'future' <String> in Stream

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

flutter instance of 'future'  in Stream

its return instance of 'future' 
I want to return value string
I want to return value string

```dart
 var channelName;
Future <String> _getrat(String id) async {
    var x = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('$id').get();
    print(x['name']);
    return channelName = await x['name'];
  }
```

```
        Container(
          child: Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance
                  .collection('ads')
                  .where('itemID', isEqualTo: itemid)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
                  return Center(
                      child: Container(
                      new CircularProgressIndicator(
                  )));
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      DocumentSnapshot mystore =
                          snapshot.data.documents[index];


                            Text('${_getrat(mystore['uid'])}'),
```

Comment: what is the output of your `print(x['name'])`?

Comment: use [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: print(x['name']); output name but ${_getrat(mystore['uid'])} return instance of 'future' <String>